# Bootstrap tooltip issue with Firefox

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I just updated Firefox to 48.0.1 from 48.0 and now I'm seeing an issue with the Bootstrap tooltip. Looking at the HTML in Firebug, it appears that Firefox is adding a new `<div>` at the bottom of the page that is not in the .jsp:

```
<div id="tooltip404721" class="tooltip fade top in" role="tooltip" style="top: 162.4px; left: 1220.5px; display: block;">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner">Delete</div>
</div>
```

This only happens if the tooltip is attached to a button - links are not affected. The links and buttons are column elements in a jQuery DataTables table. The tooltip portion of the code for link vs. button is identical.

**Link:**

```
<td><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="<c:url value='/recipe/viewRecipe/${recipe.id}'/>"
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<spring:message code="tooltip.view"></spring:message>">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></a>
```

**Button:**

```
<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="button" id="delete${recipe.id}" onclick="deleteRecipe(${recipe.id}, 
'<spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${recipe.name}</spring:escapeBody>')"
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<spring:message code="tooltip.delete"></spring:message>">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
```

This DataTables-specific setting is in a .js file included on the page:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    container : 'body'
});
```

Removing the above gets rid of the extra `<div>` but then the tooltip no longer appears with Bootstrap formatting.  Adding `data-container="body"` to the button itself didn't work either.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** 
Although I just recently noticed the issue I downgraded to 47.0.1 and still see the problem. I will keep downgrading to find out which version this starting appearing in. I don't think it's my code because the production version has the same problem as my dev version.  Also, this does not happen in Chrome but it does in Edge.

Comment: I don't think your browser or version has anything to do with it. Bootstrap tooltips have always made an extra (`div`) element to show the tooltip. Can you make a demo that shows the problem?

Comment: I agree. I just checked the production website on my laptop which is running Firefox 45 and the problem appears in that version as well.  Obviously, I jumped to the wrong conclusion since I didn't see the issue in Chrome.  It's got to be something that I changed in a recent release. I'll check it out and post an update when I (hopefully) find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I have a function that's applied to all pages that sets the input focus for form pages to the first form control.  This is because the menu contains a search input and button, which would otherwise get the focus instead of the first form input.

```
function setInputFocus() {$(':input:visible:enabled:eq(2)').focus();}
```

For some reason that I don't remember now I moved the code to toggle the tooltip (see question) **above** this focus code. That meant that the first button in the first row of the datatable ended up getting the focus, hence the tooltip being visible when the page was displayed.  Moving the tooltip toggle **after** this focus code fixed the problem.

Obviously, I should be more careful about site-wide code that is specific to a particular issue but ends up being applied to all pages...